# Deduplicating nested values that are also key in outer dictionary - Python

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates, key-value

Given an input dictionary,

```
x = {'A fantastic gift for art lovers': ['Designed for adults, this stunning piece '
                                     'of 3D art can be proudly displayed on a '
                                     'wall following a rewarding build '
                                     'experience.'],
 'Build and relax': ['Art lovers can enjoy a relaxing and immersive building '
                     'experience as they create this unique artwork from 1,810 '
                     'pieces.'],
 'Create your own artwork': ['Build Hokusai’s The Great Wave with layers of '
                             'LEGO® bricks.'],
 'Finishing touch': ['Add a decorative tile with Hokusai’s signature.'],
 'Hokusai – The Great Wave': ['Create your own artwork',
                              'Build Hokusai’s The Great Wave with layers of '
                              'LEGO® bricks.',
                              'The Great Wave comes to life!',
                              'The picture’s multiple layers create a stunning '
                              '3D effect.',
                              'Finishing touch',
                              'Add a decorative tile with Hokusai’s '
                              'signature.'],
 'Immerse yourself in the world of art': ['Listen to the set’s Soundtrack, '
                                          'tailor-made with content to enhance '
                                          'the time you spend building this '
                                          'Japanese wall art.'],
 'Recreate an iconic piece of Japanese art': ['Celebrate your passion for '
                                              'Japanese art when you build '
                                              'this incredible LEGO® version '
                                              'of Hokusai’s The Great Wave.'],
 'The Great Wave comes to life!': ['The picture’s multiple layers create a '
                                   'stunning 3D effect.']}
```

There are some duplicates in the inner list values of the keys, e.g.

```
>>> y = x['The Great Wave comes to life!']
>>> y
['The picture’s multiple layers create a stunning 3D effect.']

>>> z = x['Hokusai – The Great Wave'][3]
>>> z
'The Great Wave comes to life!'
```

The goal is to remove `y`, if `z` is in any key of `x`.

The expected output of the deduplicated `x` should look like this:

```
{'A fantastic gift for art lovers': ['Designed for adults, this stunning piece '
                                     'of 3D art can be proudly displayed on a '
                                     'wall following a rewarding build '
                                     'experience.'],
 'Build and relax': ['Art lovers can enjoy a relaxing and immersive building '
                     'experience as they create this unique artwork from 1,810 '
                     'pieces.'],
 'Hokusai – The Great Wave': ['Create your own artwork',
                              'Build Hokusai’s The Great Wave with layers of '
                              'LEGO® bricks.',
                              'The Great Wave comes to life!',
                              'The picture’s multiple layers create a stunning '
                              '3D effect.',
                              'Finishing touch',
                              'Add a decorative tile with Hokusai’s '
                              'signature.'],
 'Immerse yourself in the world of art': ['Listen to the set’s Soundtrack, '
                                          'tailor-made with content to enhance '
                                          'the time you spend building this '
                                          'Japanese wall art.'],
 'Recreate an iconic piece of Japanese art': ['Celebrate your passion for '
                                              'Japanese art when you build '
                                              'this incredible LEGO® version '
                                              'of Hokusai’s The Great Wave.']}
```

I've tried the following:

```py
    to_delete = []
    for k,v in x.items():
        for vv in v:
            if vv in x:
                to_delete.append(vv)
                
    for d in x:
        if d in x:
            del x[d]
```

And a simpler form:

```py
    for k in list(x.keys()):
        if k in x:
            for vv in x[k]:
                if vv in x:
                    del features[vv]
```

Both code snippet would work to get the expected output but there's some quirks to them and I wonder if there's a better way to process it. The code above works well on small dictionary but at millions/billions scale, it's just way too inefficient to iterate through the keys twice.

- The first snippet loops through the key-value pairs and then keep a list of keys to delete. The main issue is that the dictionary has to be looped through 2 times instead of one
- The 2nd snippet has this odd `if k in x` because when we loop through a copy of the `list(x.keys())`, the keys iterated are the old key and as the dictionary keys get dynamically popped, it's needed to check that it exists before checking if it's a duplicate

### Is there a better way to iterate through a dictionary and then delete duplicates?

E.g. maybe something like flatten the values into a set and do an intersection with the keys? Would that be a faster compute if `x` is a huge dictionary?

Comment: If a key is deleted, would you still want duplicate values from that key to also be deleted, even though that key doesn't exist anymore?

Comment: Would the value still exist in the dictionary object when a key is deleted? Cos it won't be accessible anyway.

Comment: Yes, but in your first example, you're deleting them in a separate pass. So you find all the keys first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really any way to check every item without iterating through every value in every key's list at least once; the most I can suggest is to eliminate the need for the `if _ in x` checks by using [`.get`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/get) and [`.pop`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/pop):

```py
for k in [*x]: 
    for z in x.get(k, []): 
        x.pop(z, None)
```

or with [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension):

```py
for k in [*x]: [x.pop(z,None) for z in x.get(k,[])]
```

(Using [`[*x]`](https://towardsdatascience.com/306ae44cd480) is effectively the same as using `list(x)` or `list(x.keys())` or `[k for k in x]`.)

---

Btw, it would be a bit simpler to remove the list items that are duplicates of keys, like

```py
x_dedup = {k: [z for z in y if z not in x] for k,y in x.items()}
```

and `x_dedup` would look like

> ```py
> {
>   'A fantastic gift for art lovers': ['Designed for adults, this stunning piece of 3D art can be proudly displayed on a wall following a rewarding build experience.'],
>   'Build and relax': ['Art lovers can enjoy a relaxing and immersive building experience as they create this unique artwork from 1,810 pieces.'],
>   'Create your own artwork': ['Build Hokusai’s The Great Wave with layers of LEGO® bricks.'],
>   'Finishing touch': ['Add a decorative tile with Hokusai’s signature.'],
>   'Hokusai – The Great Wave': [
>     'Build Hokusai’s The Great Wave with layers of LEGO® bricks.',
>     'The picture’s multiple layers create a stunning 3D effect.',
>     'Add a decorative tile with Hokusai’s signature.'
>   ],
>   'Immerse yourself in the world of art': ['Listen to the set’s Soundtrack, tailor-made with content to enhance the time you spend building this Japanese wall art.'],
>   'Recreate an iconic piece of Japanese art': ['Celebrate your passion for Japanese art when you build this incredible LEGO® version of Hokusai’s The Great Wave.'],
>   'The Great Wave comes to life!': ['The picture’s multiple layers create a stunning 3D effect.']
> }
> ```

Is that a viable option for you?

Comment: Definitely not the 2nd case to remove duplicates in values. But it'll be good to leave it in the answer just in case anyone in the future find it useful. Seems like `.pop` is one way to avoid the `if k in x` checks.